# Return message status in page after send mail with php

Tags: php, contacts

I try to show a message in html page, after send an e-mail.
I don't want to use javascript with an alert, just a simple message after send button.

I made a contact php page with this code:

```
<?php

$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_telefon = $_POST['cf_telefon'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];
$mail_to = 'diaconu.eduardstefan@gmail.com';;
$from = 'Mesaj nou de la:'.$field_name;
$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Telefon: '.$field_telefon."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;
$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $from, $body_message, $headers);

 ?>
```

And in html page, i insert a contact form with this code:

```
       <form  action="contact.php" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">
                                Nume
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" name="cf_name" placeholder="" id="name" class="form-control" required="true">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">
                                Email
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" name="cf_email"  placeholder="" id="email" class="form-control" required="true">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="phone">
                                Telefon
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" name="cf_telefon" id="phone" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="phone">
                                Mesaj
                            </label>
                            <textarea name="cf_message" placeholder="" rows="5" class="form-control" required="true">
                            </textarea>
                        </div>

                        <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Trimite" >
<?php if($send_mail) {
if($mail_status){
print "succes";
exit();
}
else {
print "eroare";
}
        }       
?>
                    </form>
```

Email was successfully sent, but the message isn't show. After press send button, contact form return a blank page. I want to return the same page with message. (ater refresh)

Maybe exist another way to do that? With get or something like that?

Thanks for help!

Comment: I have  updated my answer ,use that in following manner http://stackoverflow.com/a/38694374/1593084

Answer (score 1):

```
    if($_POST){
      // send mail code here
      $field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
      $field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
      $field_telefon = $_POST['cf_telefon'];
      $field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];
      $mail_to = 'diaconu.eduardstefan@gmail.com';;
      $from = 'Mesaj nou de la:'.$field_name;
      $body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
      $body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
      $body_message .= 'Telefon: '.$field_telefon."\n";
      $body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;
      $headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
      $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";
      $mail_status = mail($mail_to, $from, $body_message, $headers);
      if($mail_status){
       echo 'mail send';
      }else{
       echo 'mail not send';
      }
    }

    //place html code here below the php code
           <form  action="" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">
                                Nume
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" name="cf_name" placeholder="" id="name" class="form-control" required="true">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">
                                Email
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" name="cf_email"  placeholder="" id="email" class="form-control" required="true">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="phone">
                                Telefon
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" name="cf_telefon" id="phone" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="phone">
                                Mesaj
                            </label>
                            <textarea name="cf_message" placeholder="" rows="5" class="form-control" required="true">
                            </textarea>
                        </div>

                        <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Trimite" >

                    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I insert your code in contact.php , and now, after press send button i have an new page with message status, and i don't want this. I want to show message, after send button (after press button). For that, it's necessary to add my code in html page...maybe to create a session or something like that to store information.

Comment: That mean you don't want to redirect you page ,in fact you want to show you message on the same page,when some body click on the send button?

Comment: Yes. :) That i want.

Comment: So you could achieved this with the help of Ajax

Comment: Yes, it's an option...but i think it's more simple to return after press button the same page with the message to successfully send.

Comment: The page with contact.php code? And then, what can i use for form? Now, i have an action in form with "contact.php". Where is necessary to insert the php code? After contact form in page? Thanks for information :)

Comment: Put blank as action in from tag it will automatically redirect to same page ,with post request and then you php code is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Place your PHP in the top of the page of where your contact form is.

then change: `<form  action="contact.php" method="post">`

to

`<form  action="" method="post">`

you also need to add `name="submit"` to your submit button field and then wrap:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

// code

}
```

Also if you are trying to make sure people fill in all fields, you should use

```
if (!empty($var))
{
// code
} else
echo "Fill in this field please";
}
```

required fields can be easily bypassed by just using required within the html side.

EDIT: once all conditions are met you can simply add echo "thanks" or whatever message you want to beneath the mail() field for a success message which will output to the page above the form.